# c++ declaring a variable of a class within that class

Tags: c++, class, variables

I have the following code:

```
template <typename T>
class Node{
public: 
    Node<T>(T data){
        this->data = data;
    }
    T data;
    Node<T> left; 
    Node<T> right;
};
```

But it doesn't like how I have member variables of the same type as the class they are in because the compiler doesn't know what "Node" is.

Answer (score 6):

You want to declare `left` and `right` as `Node<T> *`:

```
Node<T> *left;
Node<T> *right;
```

The problem is not just that the compiler doesn't have the complete definition yet, but that you are trying to say a Node contains two other Nodes, so there is no sensible definition for the size of a Node.

Answer (score 0):

Create a forwarding class declaration:

```
template<typename T>
class Node;

template<typename T>
class Node {
public:
   T data;
   Node<T> left, right;
   // implementation here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This ---> `Node<T> left,right` causes compiler error. To fix it, you can declare left and right to be pointers, references, or `static` nodes:

```
template<typename T>
class Node {
public:
    Node(T data) : data(data){}
    T data;
    Node<T> *left, *right; // Ok
              /* OR */
    Node<T> &left, &right; // Ok
              /* OR */
    static Node<T> left, Node<T> right; // also Ok

    Node<T> left, right; // No way, causes error
```

};